# "To watch this video, change your restrictions in Settings.", but my restrictions are off

Tags: tv.app, appletv

I'm trying to launch a video from the TV app on my Apple TV, but when I click on it I get the error message "To watch this video, change your restrictions in Settings.". The problem is that my restrictions are turned off. I try to avoid going directly through the app that the video is played through because it blasts me with other videos before I can get to the one I want.

Comment: Getting the same issue. I have the app installed (All4) yet it still won’t play. It’s infuriating!

Answer (score 1):

After wasting 30 minutes trying to figure this same
Issue out with my Hulu. Restrictions were all off. I was having the same issue. I determined that I have the option to save storage space on the phone turned on and then my phone will uninstall apps when they are not in use. This, my Hulu app was not downloaded on the phone. Try making sure the video app is installed on the phone and try again in the TV app.

Comment: I’m having the same issue but the app in question is definitely installed.